# PostgreSQL - Comparing value based on condition (<, >, =) which written on a column?

Tags: postgresql

I have this sample database:

Table 1:

```
Type    Condition_weight      Price
  A        >50                 1000
  A      >10 & <50              500
  A        <10                  100
```

As I remember, I can do a comparison on the `Condition_weight` without doing too much on query.

My expectation query is something like this:

```
select Price from Table_1
where Type = 'A'
and {my_input_this_is a number} satisfy Condition_weight
```

I read it somewhere about this solution but cant find it again.

Comment: If the condition was a proper SQL expression, something would be possible using dynamic SQL. But translating those expressions to a proper SQL expression will be really complicated (e.g. `> 10 & <50` needs to be rewritten to `some_value > 10 and some_value < 50`). Can you change the design? If those are **always** ranges, you could define the column as an [integer range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) then you could use `where condition_weight @> 42`

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function that returns true - you will have to do the logic to extract min and max  and compare value.
pseudo code...

```
CREATE FUNCTION conditionWeightIsSatisfed(number weight)
BEGIN
set @minValue = 0;
set @MaxValue = 1000;

..... do your conversion of the text values.....


select weight >= @minValue and weight <= @maxValue

END
```

Comment: It would be a better solution to do the extraction as you are saving the record and add a minvalue and maxvalue field to the table or view